# Is Terraria SharePlay compatible?

Tags: ps4, psn, terraria-console

Can we make use of SharePlay on the PS4 for Terraria? Or have the developers blocked this functionality?

Comment: Please provide context for downvotes

Comment: The developers don't "block" functionality, it's more a question of whether or not they developed it.  Anything developed for a Sony platform always adds work, and since Terraria for anything but PC is essentially a port, it wouldn't surprise me if they hadn't added that feature to the PS4 version. The second half of your question is probably why you got downvotes.

Comment: @user1895086 please consider converting your comment to an answer as it answers my question sufficiently. Articles like [this](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-11-06-not-all-games-are-on-board-with-ps4-share-play) made me believe developers could block it.

Comment: @C_B unless you don't own the game yet, why can't you test this for yourself?

Comment: @TimmyJim you are correct, I don't own the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers don't "block" functionality, it's more a question of whether or not they developed it. Anything developed for a Sony platform always adds work, and since Terraria for anything but PC is essentially a port, it wouldn't surprise me if they hadn't added that feature to the PS4 version. The second half of your question is probably why you got downvotes.

Additionally, the article you referenced [here](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-11-06-not-all-games-are-on-board-with-ps4-share-play) supports that theory, specifically mentioning it having gone untested and so the feature was blocked.  To clarify my above statement, developers are *capable* of blocking SharePlay, but either toggle it off because they know their game doesn't perform well under those conditions due to a lack of development with SharePlay in mind, or because of regional legal restrictions on certain scenes or visuals (in which case you get a message saying you're not allowed to see it in your region).  Seeing as the goriest moment in Terraria is fighting the Wall of Flesh, it is unlikely subject to the censorship described in that article, and would be based on whether or not the content were developed to allow for SharePlay to function.